# Function with return value char* returning garbage

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a utility class that I can re-use, that converts a `std::string to a char*`:

```
char* Foo::stringConvert(std::string str){
      std::string newstr = str;
      // Convert std::string to char*
      boost::scoped_array<char> writable(new char[newstr.size() + 1]);
      std::copy(newstr.begin(), newstr.end(), writable.get());
      writable[newstr.size()] = '\0'; 
      // Get the char* from the modified std::string
      return writable.get();
}
```

The code works when I tried to load the output from within the stringConvert function, however when used in other parts of my application, this function returns garbage.

For example:

```
Foo foo;
char* bar = foo.stringConvert(str);
```

The above code returns garbage.
Is there any workaround for this kind of issue?

Comment: It would have been easier to answer the question if you hadn't omitted the code.

Comment: @cppcoder boost::scoped_array<char> writable(new char[newstr.size() + 1]);

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949

Comment: @TonyDelroy Actually the shown in the link is basically the same with my code. I will update the code in the question for clarification

Comment: @xybrek: you haven't understood it... when you return only the .get() result, the scoped_array destructor still deletes the memory you newed while the function returns... the char* addresses that invalid memory region....

Comment: @TonyDelroy Yah I know about that, because my code works when not passed as a function of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just use `std::string.c_str()`? This is a library method that does just what you need.

Comment: I can't use the c_str() function because, I will get this error:  cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPSTR'(char*)

Comment: You can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342772/convert-lptstr-to-char looks similiar to your case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume `writable` is an object with automatic duration that destructs the `char*` it contains in the destructor - that's your problem - whatever `writable.get()` returns is no longer valid.

Just return a `std::string` instead, why on earth do you need a raw `char *`?

Comment: I can't use the c_str() function because, I will get this error:  cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPSTR'(char*)

Comment: @xybrek why is `bar` a `char*`? Are you modifying the string? Do you need to modify the string?

Comment: char* is the parameter that needs to be passed on one of the function in my app

Comment: I mean the library I'm using with my app needs char* as parameter

Comment: @xybrek the you need to use strcpy.