# What is the difference and the relationship of char and CString

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Can someone explain me the difference and the relationship between the char * and CString?... Thanks.

Comment: `CString` is designed to be used by C++ code, while a raw `char*` should basically never be used in C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CString is a class packed with different functionalities.. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

char * is just a regular c++ data type.

CString is used mostly in MFC applications.

Comment: Yeah I'm using it in a MFC application.

Answer (score 3):

There are few important differences.

`char *` is a pointer to `char`. Generally you can't say if it a single char, or a beginning of a string, and what is the length. All those things are dictated by program logic and some conventions, i.e. standard C functions, like to use `const char *` as inputs. You need to manage memory allocated for strings manually.

`CString` is a macro. Depending on your program compilation options, it can be defined to either the `CStringA` or `CStringW` class. There are differences and similarities.

The difference is that `CStringA`operates with non-Unicode data (similar to `char*`), and `CStringW` is a Unicode string (similar to `wchar_t*`).

Both classes, however, are equivalent in the aspect of string manipulation and storage management. They are closer to the standard C++ `std::string` and `std::wstring` classes.

Apart from that, both `CStringA` and `CStringW` provide the capability to convert strings to and from Unicode form.

Comment: CStringA/CStringW and std::string/std::wstring are quite unlike eachother. The only thing they have in common is they're both C++ classes manipulating strings. This difference is quite obvious when trying to make ATL/WTL user interface code using CString play nicely with backend code using std::string/wstring and standard containers.

Comment: @Zadirion Both classes provide a member function that returns a pointer to a C-style string, which makes interop trivial. Differences between their implementation are irrelevant as God intended them to be. When considering the use of a class, all one should care about is the interface.

Comment: @CodyGray of course, converting between them is not rocket science. But lack of implicit conversion and the fact that CString does not model the container concept really makes it an ugly to use thing, which one would rather avoid if it wasn't needed by the UI framework. On the upside though, CString is a bit more lightweight, and it also has the useful Format method which you can only get through boost::format if you like writing standard code.

Answer (score 2):

a CString will be an array of `char` and a `char*` will be a pointer into the array of `char` with which you can iterate the characters of the string.

Actually from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> `CString` is based on the `TCHAR` data type. If the symbol `_UNICODE` is defined for your program, `TCHAR` is defined as type `wchar_t`, a 16-bit character type; otherwise, it is defined as char, the normal 8-bit character type. Under Unicode, then, `CString` objects are composed of 16-bit characters. *Without Unicode, they are composed of 8-bit char type.*

Answer (score 1):

CString is a sequence of TCHAR-s rather then char*. The main difference is that if UNICODE is defined CString will be sequence of wchar. Actually depending on that macro CString will be tpyedef -ed either to CStringA or CStringW. Another major difference is that CString is a **class** while char* is simply a pointer to character.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of TCHAR, CString can be either CStringA or CStringW.

That said, `CString` is a wrapper over an array of chars, that enables you to easily treat that array of chars as a string, and operate on it in manners relevant to the string type.

For the relationship between them, here is something that illustrates it easily. You can convert between char * and CString like this:

`CString str = "abc"; // const char[3] or char * to CString`

and

`const char * p = str.Get()` // CString to const char *

Answer (score 1):

A `CString` is a class and provides lots of functionalities that a `char *` doesnt. A `char *` is just a pointer to char or chars array.

A CString contains a buffer that is roughtly the same as a char * : `LPTSTR GetBuffer( int nMinBufLength );`

For the difference between `LPTSTR` and `char *` go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342772/convert-lptstr-to-char) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/1b994ff3-da28-46a8-90ef-6c7fab8dcd21/)

Answer (score 0):

CString is a wrapper class around a char* to provide some useful additional functions and to hide the memory allocation/deallocation from the user.
There is not much difference in performance terms so if you are using MFC classes, you might as well use a CString.