# Generate EVP_PKEY from Private Key Bytes In PEM Format

Tags: openssl, private-key

I have a private key bytes stored in PEM format, in a variable of Type `LPSTR`. i.e

```
LPSTR pPrivateKeyInPem;
```

Now I need to generate an `EVP_PKEY` using `pPrivateKeyInPem`, so that it can be loaded into an `SSL_CTX` Object using the `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey()` API of Openssl.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format your code - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I would also recommend you to use smaller sentences for readability. Please edit to add anything necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Wtower . I will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll omit conversion from LPSTR to char*, which is covered here: [Convert lptstr to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342772/convert-lptstr-to-char)

For the OpenSSL part

```
BIO *mem;
mem = BIO_new_mem_buf(pkey, -1); //pkey is of type char*

key = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(mem, NULL, NULL, 0);
```