# How do I convert a string to a char* in c++?

Tags: c++, string, char

I have an error in my program: "could not convert from string to char*". How do I perform this conversion?

Comment: NONE of the posted answers answer the actual question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you can settle for a `const char*`, you just need to call the `c_str()` method on it:

```
const char *mycharp = mystring.c_str();
```

If you really need a modifiable `char*`, you will need to make a copy of the string's buffer. A `vector` is an ideal way of handling this for you:

```
std::vector<char> v(mystring.length() + 1);
std::strcpy(&v[0], mystring.c_str());
char* pc = &v[0];
```

Answer (score 15):

Invoke `str.c_str()` to get a `const char*`:

```
const char *pch = str.c_str();
```

Note that the resulting `const char*` is only valid until `str` is changed or destroyed.

---

However, if you really need a non-`const`, you probably shouldn't use `std::string`, as it wasn't designed to allow changing its underlying data behind its back. That said, you can get a pointer to its data by invoking `&str[0]` or `&*str.begin()`.

The ugliness of this should be considered a feature. In C++98, `std::string` isn't even required to store its data in a contiguous chunk of memory, so this might explode into your face. I think has changed, but I cannot even remember whether this was for C++03 or the upcoming next version of the standard, C++1x.

If you need to do this, consider using a `std::vector<char>` instead. You can access its data the same way: `&v[0]` or `&*v.begin()`.

Answer (score 9):

```
//assume you have an std::string, str. 
char* cstr = new char[str.length() +1]; 
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str()); 

//eventually, remember to delete cstr
delete[] cstr;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `c_str()` method on a `string` object to get a `const char*` pointer.  Warning: The returned pointer is no longer valid if the `string` object is modified or destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

Since you wanted to go from a `string` to a `char*` (ie, not a `const char*`) you can do this BUT BEWARE:  there be dragons here:

```
string foo = "foo";
char* foo_c = &foo[0];
```

If you try to modify the contents of the string, you're well and truly on your own.

Comment: The problem is not just modifying the contents - the contents of a string aren't guaranteed to be contiguous, so it might not work at all.

Comment: I may be wrong there, according to the accepted answer to this question it's guaranteed to be contiguous in the new standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring

Answer (score 2):

If `const char*` is good for you then use this: `myString.c_str()`

If you really need `char*` and know for sure that `char*` WILL NOT CHANGE then you can use this: `const_cast<char*>(myString.c_str())`

If `char*` may change then you need to copy the string into something else and use that instead. That something else may be `std::vector`, or `new char[]`, it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) returns a c-string with the same contents as the `string` object.

```
std::string str("Hello");
const char* cstr = str.c_str();
```