# How is stored a vector<string> in memory

Tags: c++, memory

I am working on a project where I absolutly need to have data contiguous in memory.
I want to store some (maximum 100) string (I don't know the actual size of each string). So I will create a vector of string of 100 elements.

```
std::vector<std::string> vect;
vect.reserve(100)
```

But a String can be of any size. So how does it work? Is my vector reallocated everytime I change a string? Or is a std::string simply like a pointer to the first character of the string like a char* would be for a C string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring

Comment: `std::string` behaves like a pointer in your example. There is small string optimization where small strings (small means ~20-40 characters) are inside the `std::string` itself. If you require all characters to be in contiguous memory you will have to use a `vector<char>` and do it manually.

Comment: thank you, that kind of information are precious, because string could do background thing, that's why I asked this. And what you say is that it does some optimization that could make it not contiguous ?

Comment: A `std::string` is dynamically allocated, and is guaranteed to have *local* contiguous memory at all times (meaning the individual string will have contiguous memory). However, this says nothing about it's contiguity within your `vect` of `string`s. I'm not aware of a way to guarantee contiguity in this way.

Comment: @cmbasnett the constructor of `std::string` has an optional template argument for an `std::allocator`. You can define a memory pool and each time you create a `string` it will be allocated in there. You can make sure that all string are in a contiguous memory block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Each `string` will be an instance of class `string` and that instance will contain a `char*`.
2. The `string` objects in the vector will be in contiguous memory.
3. The chars of each `string` will be in contiguous memory
4. All The chars of all the strings will not be in contiguous memory, unless you define a custom `std::allocator` for the strings
5. The location in memory of the strings may change when you increase the size of the `vector` or call `shrink_to_fit`
6. The location in memory of the chars of each `string` may change when you increase the size of the `string`
7. The `vector` will not be reallocated if you modify or remove one of the strings
8. There is something called *Small String Optimization*. If that comes into play the chars of each `string` will be stored within the `string` instead of another location pointed to by `char*`

Comment: So a string is actually just an encapsulation of a char*

Comment: It's templated but if you are using just default std::string then yes.

Comment: @FreeYourSoul It has more stuff like capacity and size, not just the `char *`.

Answer (score 3):

The data in `std::vector` is laid out contiguosly. However `std::string`s implementation does not guarantee that the memory holding the character array is stored locally to the class itself. How could it? Like you said you don't know how large the string will be.

A lot of array like structures have a layout like follows:

```
class string
{
    T * begin; 
    T * end;
    T * capacity;
}
```

Which means that your vector of 100 strings will have 100 instances of a class layout that POINTS to the memory where the string is stored.

Now if you need to pack memory allocations as tightly as possible and still want to use `std::string` you can write a custom [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

Maybe you can write the string data into a char array and have a second container that stores the lengths of each individual string + NULL terminator.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `string` is implementation defined and has actually changed between different versions of certain compilers (for example from gcc 4.9 to 5.0). The is absolutely no guarantee that the `char`s in consecutive `string`s are contiguous in memory, **even if you use a custom allocator**.

So if you really need the `char`s to be contiguous in memory, you must use just a `vector<char>`.