# Are there any issues reading directly into an std::string?

Tags: c++, string

I've seen in code a direct read into `std::string` where the contents are intended to be interpreted as a string as follows:

```
std::string note;
note.resize(n);
read( &note[0], n );
```

Assume that n is of a fixed size, as in a parsing scenario.

Are there are any issues with reading directly into a string? I have seen a lot of uses of ifstreams, but it seems excessive in this case.

Comment: It's basically the same as reading it into a `char` buffer. If you're sure your buffer is big enough there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It really depends on the use case.  If the data is not really a string then you may want to consider a `std::vector` so you do not "lie" to yourself.

Comment: There is no such thing as *good practice*. There are techniques suitable to achieve a particular goal or not suitable for a specific set of reasons. Stop thinking about best practices, think like an engineer.

Comment: @SergeyA I understand what you mean. By good practice, I meant, in this scenario, are there specific reasons not to do this.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. I've clarified for the intent of interpreting as a string.

Comment: @GillBates It looks like you're right in practice. I found the following link that says until c++11, a string wasn't defined to have contiguous storage, but in practice it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if it's a text file made by several lines, I find the `std::string` class not a good choice as a "container"; I would prefer just a `std::vector<char>`, or if you want to do some additional parsing and break the file into its single lines, a `std::vector<std::string>`.

I'd also pay attention to the **encoding** used by the file: is it UTF-8? Is it some other `char`-based encoding?

For example, if the file is UTF-16, reading it as a raw sequence of bytes into a `std::string` would be very misleading (and bug prone).

Moreover, it's important also to pay attention to the **size** of the file. If you have a gigantic text file (e.g. 5GB) and you are building a 32-bit Windows application, your code won't work (as 32-bit processes on Windows are limited to 2GB by default). In such cases, reading the file content in smaller chunks (or using memory-mapped file techniques with smaller *"views"* on the file) may be a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks. Encoding is not something I considered.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way: “What's the worst that could happen?”

Are you obtaining a file from the local user? And if they supply a file that's too big, perhaps their machine will thrash, or even kill your program with an out-of-memory error?

Do you expect the user to do that often enough to worry about?

Alternatively:

Are you obtaining the file from a network source or untrusted user? Would giving that user the ability to potentially thrash your system or kill your application constitute a risk?

Comment: In answer to your prompt, I found the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring which partially addresses my question.