# What winapi C function call can I use to convert unicode to ascii and vice versa?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, winapi

It has to work with a C program so it has to be a winapi c call

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Are there examples on how to use it?

Comment: @shawn, you can find some example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215963/how-do-you-properly-use-widechartomultibyte). Those function are very commonly used, so you'll have no problem finding other examples on the web. They both take about a million arguments, but for simple cases you can use the defaults.

Answer (score 3):

All 128 ASCII characters convert to the unicode code point with the same value (see [ASCII in unicode glossary](http://unicode.org/glossary/)). Conversion, in C (have no idea about the other tags in your question), is as easy as assignment: `unicodevalue = asciivalue;` or `asciivalue = unicodevalue;` though you probably want to make sure that `unicodevalue` in the last staetement represents an ASCII character before converting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution which comes along with CRT ; consider this if you are using Visual studio.

[mbstowcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the links have sample C++ code too.