# How to convert between widecharacter and multi byte character string in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

I have a windows application where string types are `WCHAR*`. I need to convert this into `char*` for passing into a C API. I am using `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte` functions to perform the conversion.

But for some reason, the conversion is not proper. I am seeing lot of gibberish in the output. Following code is a modified version found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215963/how-do-you-properly-use-widechartomultibyte) stackoverflow answer.

```
WCHAR* convert_to_wstring(const char* str)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, (int)strlen(str), NULL, 0);
    WCHAR* wstrTo = (WCHAR*)malloc(size_needed);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)strlen(str), wstrTo, size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}

char* convert_from_wstring(const WCHAR* wstr)
{
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, (int)wcslen(wstr), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char* strTo = (char*)malloc(size_needed);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, (int)wcslen(wstr), strTo, size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}

int main()
{
    const WCHAR* wText = L"Wide string";
    const char* text = convert_from_wstring(wText);
    std::cout << text << "\n";
    std::cout << convert_to_wstring("Multibyte string") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you feel the need to re-write the other code, instead of just use it as-is?  Clearly you have not read the documetnation for the functions being used. And you do realize that you can't output a `WCHAR*` using `std:cout`, don't you? you would need to use `std::wcout` instead.

Comment: What do you expect to see when using `cout` to output `WCHAR*`?

Comment: I could. Only reason is in that code it uses std::string and std::wstring. It is another level of indirection for me. Because all the other parts of code uses char* and WCHAR*.

Comment: @Appu: well, then you are not really taking advantage of C++, are you? You may has well just code in C instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes. I know it. It is a legacy code base and changes are not that easy to make.

Comment: So what if the system is largely based on `char*`/`wchar_t*`? That is what the `std::string::c_str()` and `std::wstring::c_str()` are meant for.  Let the STL handle the memory management for you (especially since you are getting it all wrong anyway).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your conversion functions are buggy.

The return value of `MultiByteToWideChar()` is a **number of wide characters**, not a **number of bytes** like you are currently treating it.  You need to multiple the value by `sizeof(WCHAR)` when calling `malloc()`.

You are also not taking into account that the return value DOES NOT include space for a null terminator, because you are not passing `-1` in the `cbMultiByte` parameter. [Read the `MultiByteToWideChar()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx):

> `cbMultiByte` [in]
>   Size, in bytes, of the string indicated by the `lpMultiByteStr` parameter. Alternatively, this parameter can be set to -1 if the string is null-terminated. Note that, if `cbMultiByte` is 0, the function fails.
>
> If this parameter is -1, the function processes the entire input string, including the terminating null character. Therefore, the resulting Unicode string has a terminating null character, and the length returned by the function includes this character.
>
> If this parameter is set to a positive integer, the function processes exactly the specified number of bytes. **If the provided size does not include a terminating null character, the resulting Unicode string is not null-terminated, and the returned length does not include this character.**
>
> ...
>
> Return value
>
> Returns the **number of characters** written to the buffer indicated by `lpWideCharStr` if successful. If the function succeeds and `cchWideChar` is 0, the return value is the required size, **in characters**, for the buffer indicated by `lpWideCharStr`.

You are not null-terminating your output string.

The same goes with your `convert_from_wstring()` function. [Read the `WideCharToMultiByte()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx):

> `cchWideChar` [in]
>   Size, in characters, of the string indicated by `lpWideCharStr`. Alternatively, this parameter can be set to -1 if the string is null-terminated. If `cchWideChar` is set to 0, the function fails.
>
> If this parameter is -1, the function processes the entire input string, including the terminating null character. Therefore, the resulting character string has a terminating null character, and the length returned by the function includes this character.
>
> If this parameter is set to a positive integer, the function processes exactly the specified number of characters. **If the provided size does not include a terminating null character, the resulting character string is not null-terminated, and the returned length does not include this character**.
>
> ...
>
> Return value
>
> Returns the **number of bytes** written to the buffer pointed to by `lpMultiByteStr` if successful. If the function succeeds and `cbMultiByte` is 0, the return value is the required size, **in bytes**, for the buffer indicated by `lpMultiByteStr`.

That being said, your `main()` code is leaking the allocated strings.  Since they are allocated with `malloc()`, you need to deallocate them with `free()` when you are done using them:

Also, you cannot pass a `WCHAR*` string to `std::cout`.  Well, you can, but it has no `operator<<` for wide string input, but it does have an `operator<<` for `void*` input, so it will just end up outputting the *memory address* that the `WCHAR*` is pointing at, not the actual characters.  If you want to output wide strings, use `std::wcout` instead.

Try something more like this:

```
WCHAR* convert_to_wstring(const char* str)
{
    int str_len = (int) strlen(str);
    int num_chars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, str_len, NULL, 0);
    WCHAR* wstrTo = (WCHAR*) malloc((num_chars + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    if (wstrTo)
    {
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, str_len, wstrTo, num_chars);
        wstrTo[num_chars] = L'\0';
    }
    return wstrTo;
}

CHAR* convert_from_wstring(const WCHAR* wstr)
{
    int wstr_len = (int) wcslen(wstr);
    int num_chars = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, wstr_len, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    CHAR* strTo = (CHAR*) malloc((num_chars + 1) * sizeof(CHAR));
    if (strTo)
    {
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, wstr_len, strTo, num_chars, NULL, NULL);
        strTo[num_chars] = '\0';
    }
    return strTo;
}

int main()
{
    const WCHAR* wText = L"Wide string";
    const char* text = convert_from_wstring(wText);
    std::cout << text << "\n";
    free(text);

    const WCHAR *wtext = convert_to_wstring("Multibyte string");
    std::wcout << wtext << "\n";
    free(wtext);

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you really should be using `std::string` and `std::wstring` instead of `char*` and `wchar_t*` for better memory management:

```
std::wstring convert_to_wstring(const std::string &str)
{
    int num_chars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo;
    if (num_chars)
    {
        wstrTo.resize(num_chars);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), &wstrTo[0], num_chars);
    }
    return wstrTo;
}

std::string convert_from_wstring(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    int num_chars = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), wstr.length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo;
    if (num_chars > 0)
    {
        strTo.resize(num_chars);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), wstr.length(), &strTo[0], num_chars, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return strTo;
}

int main()
{
    const WCHAR* wText = L"Wide string";
    const std::string text = convert_from_wstring(wText);
    std::cout << text << "\n";

    const std::wstring wtext = convert_to_wstring("Multibyte string");
    std::wcout << wtext << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If you are using C++11 or later, have a look at the [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) class for converting between UTF strings, eg:

```
std::wstring convert_to_wstring(const std::string &str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(str);
}

std::string convert_from_wstring(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(wstr);
}
```

If you need to interact with other code that is based on `char*`/`wchar_t*`, `std::string` as a constructor for accepting `char*` input and a `c_str()` method that can be used for `char*` output, and the same goes for `std::wstring` and `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Has anyone done performance comparison of recent implementation of `wstring_convert` vs. `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()`?

Comment: The C++11 examples saved me from hours of frustration... kudos for that Remy. However I found another "version" with some error handling, maybe you want to add it into your answer ? I put it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/hq2grb84

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this on Windows is to use `_bstr_` from

```
#include <comdef.h> // _bstr_t

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::wstring convert_to_wstring(const char* str)
{
    return _bstr_t(str);
}

std::string convert_from_wstring(const WCHAR* wstr)
{
    return _bstr_t(wstr);
}

int main()
{
    const auto text = convert_from_wstring(L"Wide string");
    const auto wide_text = convert_to_wstring("Multibyte string");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, notice how much easier it is to return `std::wstring` and `std::string`.

Comment: The documentation on `_bstr_t::_bstr_t(const char*)` is ambiguous: *This constructor first performs a multibyte to Unicode conversion.*. Which encoding does it use to convert from multibyte to Unicode?

Comment: I assume it will use OEM encoding and not UTF8. And OP is converting to/from UTF8 string.

Comment: @Paul I doubt it uses the OEM codepage, it probably uses the "ANSI" codepage (CP_ACP).

Comment: @Anders Doesn't matter in this context, it still doesn't solve OP's task (convert UTF8 string to/from UTF16 string).

Comment: `_bstr_t` is not a general Windows solution, it is a Visual Studio specific solution. Other Windows compilers may not have it. And worse, since it wraps a BSTR, it uses the COM memory manager instead of the compiler's own RTL memory manager. And then it has to be copied to `std::wstring`, so you may be using mess code but you are doing a double allocation.