# Converting to UTF-8 from ToUnicodeEx()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, utf-8, ucs2

I get input using GetAsyncKeyState() which I then convert to unicode using ToUnicodeEx():

```
wchar_t character[1];
ToUnicodeEx(i, scanCode, keyboardState, character, 1, 0, layout);
```

I can write this to a file using wfstream like so:

```
wchar_t buffer[128]; // Will not print unicode without these 2 lines
file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, 128);
file.put(0xFEFF); // BOM needed since it's encoded using UCS-2 LE
file << character[0];
```

When I open this file in Notepad++ it's in UCS-2 LE, when I want it to be in UTF-8 format. I believe ToUnicodeEx() is returning it in UCS-2 LE format, it also only works with wide chars. Is there any way to do this using either fstream or wfstream by somehow converting into UTF-8 first? Thanks!

Comment: `ToUnicodeEx` to get UTF-16LE then `WideCharToMultiByte` to get UTF-8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999597/4454124

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

For example:

```
wchar_t buffer[LEN]; // input buffer
char output_buffer[OUT_LEN]; // output buffer where the utf-8 string will be written
int num = WideCharToMultiByte(
    CP_UTF8,
    0,
    buffer,
    number_of_characters_in_buffer, // or -1 if buffer is null-terminated
    output_buffer,
    size_in_bytes_of_output_buffer,
    NULL,
    NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows API generally refers to UTF-16 as *unicode* which is a little confusing. This means most unicode Win32 function calls operate on or give utf-16 strings.

So `ToUnicodeEx` returns a utf-16 string.

If you need this as utf 8 you'll need to convert it using [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help, I've managed to solve my problem with additional help from a blog post about WideCharToMultiByte() and UTF-8 [here](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2008/10/20/writing-utf-8-files-in-c/).

This function converts wide char arrays to a UTF-8 string:

```
// Takes in pointer to wide char array and length of the array
std::string ConvertCharacters(const wchar_t* buffer, int len)
{
    int nChars = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, buffer, len, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    if (nChars == 0)
    {
        return u8"";
    }

    std::string newBuffer;
    newBuffer.resize(nChars);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, buffer, len, const_cast<char*>(newBuffer.c_str()), nChars, NULL, NULL);
    return newBuffer;
}
```