# I need UTF8 encoded representation of a hex string, not UTF16

Tags: c++, c++builder

I need to get UTF8 representation of the following hex value, not UTF16. I am using C++ builder 11

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF8");
String tb64 = UTF8String(U"D985");//Hex value of the letter م or M in arabic

 std::wstring hex;
for(int i =1; i < tb64.Length()+1; ++i)
        hex += tb64[i];

int len = hex.length();
std::wstring newString;
std::wstring byte;
String S;

for(int i=0; i< len; i+=4)
{

 byte = hex.substr(i,4);

 wchar_t  chr =( wchar_t ) ( int) wcstol(byte.c_str(), 0, 16);
     newString.push_back(chr);
     S = newString.c_str();
}
```

the output should be م which is M in Arabic not garbage

https://dencode.com/en/string?v=D985&oe=UTF-8&nl=crlf

Comment: You are doing something wrong and ask to fix your incorrect solution. This is an example of [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain : WHY? What are you trying to achieve, what are the requirements not the way you try to achieve them. There are many simpler ways to get this character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215963/how-do-you-properly-use-widechartomultibyte/215973

Comment: There is `MultiByteToWideChar` function in Win32 API. With `CP_UTF8` for first parameter.

Comment: Output of what is wrong? This fragment produces no output.

Comment: unicode map says it's `0x0645`. Can't you just output `م`? Where do you get your input from?

Comment: I am decoding a QR Code encoded in a utf8 hexed string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the hex string to a `UTF8String`, and then assigning that to a `(Unicode)String`, which will convert the UTF-8 to UTF-16. Then you are creating a separate `std::wstring` from the UTF-16 characters. `std::wstring` uses UTF-16 on Windows and UTF-32 on other platforms.

All of those string conversions are unnecessary, since you are dealing with hex characters in the ASCII range.  So just iterate the characters of the original hex string as-is, no conversion needed.

In any case, you are trying to decode each 4-digit hex sequence directly into a binary Unicode codepoint number. But in this case, codepoint [U+D985](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d985/index.htm) is not a valid Unicode character.

`"D985"` is actually the hex-encoded **UTF-8 bytes** of the Unicode character `م` (codepoint [U+0645](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0645/index.htm)), so you need to convert each **pair of 2 hex digits** into a single byte, and store the bytes as-is into a `UTF8String`, not a `std::wstring`.

The RTL has a [`StrToInt()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt) function that can decode a hex-encoded `UnicodeString` into an integer, which you can then treat as a byte in this case.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
String hex = _D("D985");
int len = hex.Length();

UTF8String utf8;
for(int i = 1; i <= len; i += 2) {
    utf8 += static_cast<char>(StrToInt(_D("0x") + hex.Substring(i, 2)));
}

/* alternatively:
UTF8String utf8;
utf8.SetLength(len / 2);

for(int i = 1, j = 1; i <= len; i += 2, ++j) {
    utf8[j] = static_cast<char>(StrToInt(_D("0x") + hex.Substring(i, 2)));
}
*/

// use utf8 as needed...
```

If you need to convert the decoded UTF-8 to UTF-16, just assign the `UTF8String` as-is to a `UnicodeString`, eg:

```cpp
UnicodeString utf16 = utf8;
```

Or, you can alternatively store the decoded bytes into a [`TBytes`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TBytes) and then use the [`GetString()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetString) method of [`TEncoding::UTF8`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.UTF8), eg:

```cpp
String hex = _D("D985");
int len = hex.Length();

TBytes utf8;
utf8.Length = len / 2;
for(int i = 1, j = 0; i <= len; i += 2, ++j) {
    utf8[j] = static_cast<System::Byte>(StrToInt(_D("0x") + hex.Substring(i, 2)));
}

UnicodeString utf16 = TEncoding::UTF8->GetString(utf8);
// use utf16 as needed...
```

---

I just thought of a slightly simpler solution - the RTL also has a [`HexToBin()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.HexToBin) function, which can decode an entire hex-encoded string into a full byte array in one operation, eg:

```cpp
String hex = _D("D985");

UTF8String utf8;
utf8.SetLength(hex.Length() / 2);
HexToBin(hex.c_str(), &utf8[1], utf8.Length());

/* or:
TBytes utf8;
utf8.Length = hex.Length() / 2;
HexToBin(hex.c_str(), &utf8[0], utf8.Length);
*/

// use utf8 as needed...
```

Comment: Note `D985` is a sequence of bytes which interpreted as UTF-8 represents desired character. So  conversion to `int` from this hex value is completely off track and will provide invalid value.

Comment: @MarekR that is incorrect. `"D985"` in this case is a **hex encoded string representation** of the raw UTF-8 bytes. The code I presented is converting the substring `"0xD9"` into a binary byte whose numeric value is `0xD9`, then the substring `"0x85"` into a binary byte whose numeric value is `0x85`, and so on. Thus retrieving the actual raw UTF-8 bytes from the hex string.

Comment: Thank you both solutions worked

Comment: @RamezAbiad I just added another solution.