# Win32 <tchar.h> TCHAR to UTF-8?

Tags: winapi, unicode, tchar

How can I convert a Win32 `TCHAR` string from `<tchar.h>` to a UTF-8 string? I haven't found any documentation how to do that, only `TCHAR` to a multibyte string (`wcstombs()`), which relies on the current locale.

I cannot use `setlocale()` etc, as I write a DLL.

I tried `TCHAR` to `char` with `wcstombs()`, but that relies on the current locale, and does not always give a UTF8 string. I need a solution which does not use the current locale.

Comment: One problem is that `TCHAR` is not a fixed type. It could be a `char` or a `wchar_t` depending on a macro.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but `TCHAR` should be controlled by your compiler flags, which are set by YOU.  It won't change unexpectedly.

Comment: Don't use `wcstombs`, use `WideCharToMultibyte`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215963/how-do-you-properly-use-widechartomultibyte

Answer (score 2):

`TCHAR` maps to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined during compiling.

If `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, a `wchar_t` string is encoded in UTF-16 on Windows, so you can use `WideCharToMultiByte()` (or equivalent) with the `CP_UTF8` codepage to convert a UTF-16 `wchar_t` string to a UTF-8 `char` string.

If `TCHAR` is `char`, you have to know ahead of time which locale the `char` string is encoded in, before you can *correctly* convert it to UTF-8.  If you do not know the locale, you are SOL if the `char` string contains any non-ASCII characters.  Otherwise, you can first use `MultiByteToWideChar()` (or equivalent) with an appropriate codepage to convert the `char` string to a UTF-16 `wchar_t` string, and then convert that to UTF-8 as above.