How to use DeviceCapabilities() DC_BINNAMES in C++/CLI
How to use DeviceCapabilities() DC_BINNAMES in C++/CLI ?
LPTSTR sizeBuf = ...
DeviceCapabilities(printerName.c_str(), NULL, DC_BINNAMES, sizeBuf, NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++) std::wcout << sizeBuf[i] << << "\n";

Thanks

Why is C++/CLI mentioned ? Isn't this pure native C++ code ?

You need to allocate an array of 24-char arrays, and then pass in the address of that outer array so DeviceCapabilities() can fill in the inner arrays, eg:
nCount = DeviceCapabilitiesW(printerName.c_str(), NULL, DC_BINNAMES, NULL, NULL);
if (nCount < 0) ... // error handling

std::vector<WCHAR[24]> binNames(nCount);

nCount = DeviceCapabilitiesW(printerName.c_str(), NULL, DC_BINNAMES, reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(binNames.data()), NULL);
if (nCount < 0) ... // error handling

Just watch out that if any given name is exactly 24 characters then it will not be null-terminated, so you have to account for that, eg:
for (int i = 0; i < nCount; ++i) {
    WCHAR binName[25] = {0}; // +1 for null terminator
    std::copy_n(binNames[i], 24, binName);
    std::wcout << binName << << L'\n';
}


Thanks, I have the same question for DC_BINS ?

Ok, I have an other question : how to convert binName (WCHAR) to std::string ?

@pol9595 for your last question maybe this will help: How do I convert wchar_t* to std::string?.

@pol9595 for DC_BINS, simply use WORD instead of WCHAR[24]. As for converting binName, why std::string and not std::wstring? If you really need std::string then you should use DeviceCapabilitiesA() with CHAR[24] instead.

Use the same approach for DC_BINS except that the buffer would be a std::vector<WORD> (and you don't have to worry about string termination).  Each value returned is an ID number for one of the printer's paper sources.  The Windows headers define the most common IDs, like DMBIN_AUTO and DMBIN_MANUAL, but printers with many papers sources may have higher valued IDs that don't correspond to the pre-defined ones.  If you get vectors for both binNames and binIDs (for the same printer), then, for each i, binNames[i] is the name that corresponds to binIDs[i].

to convert to std::string,
std::wstring ws = std::wstring(binName); std::string s(ws.begin(), ws.end());

@pol9595 That will only work for ASCII.

@pol9595 that approach simply copies each wchar_t as-is and truncates each one to char, chopping off the top bits of each character. That will not work for non-ASCII characters. To assign a std::wstring to a std::string without data loss, you need a charset conversion, such as with WideCharToMultiByte() or equivalent.

I tried, it work for utf-8 (é)

@pol9595 No, it does not work. That approach only works for ASCII characters 0-127, which have the same values in UTF-8 and UTF-16. é is outside of the ASCII range. If you assign a wchar_t to a char for values outside of ASCII , you WILL get data loss.  Besides, é in UTF-8 is 2 chars: 0xC3 0xA9, but in UTF-16 is one wchar_t: 0x00E9, so you cannot just COPY é as-is back and worth, it needs to be CONVERTED properly from one encoding to another.

I don't understand, if data is lost, I have a french Windows, why in my app C++/CLI is dispalyed "Sélection automatique", "Bac à env." ?

@pol9595 in a std::wstring on Windows, Unicode character é has a wchar_t value of 0x00E9. Copying that value as-is into a std::string will truncate the wchar_t value of 0x00E9 into a char value of 0xE9.  In some ANSI charsets (which apparently includes your French charset), 0xE9 happens to represent é. Your std::string is being interpreted as French, not as UTF-8. But you can't rely on that behavior for every character in every codepage. Truncating a wchar_t into a char is data loss. It is not a proper data conversion between different encodings.

You're right, this code is better ? #include <atlbase.h>  std::wstring ws = std::wstring(binName); CW2A wtoa(ws.c_str(), CP_UTF8); std::string s = wtoa.m_psz;

@pol9595 That is a proper data conversion, yes. Though, you don't need the intermediate std::wstring in that case, or even the wtoa variable: std::string s = CW2A(binName, CP_UTF8).m_psz; However, unless you are writing this code in an ActiveX/COM project then I would suggest staying away from ATL for any non COM-related work. Use WideCharToMultiByte() instead, or std::wstring_convert (deprecated in C++17 but still works), or ICU (integrated into Windows in Win10 v1703), or ICONV, etc. Plenty of options.

Finally I used WideCharToMultiByte(), https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999597
